# PHP if image name with this extension doesn't exist in the directory, then show XXX.png

Tags: php, magento

I'm pretty new in PHP and what I would like to do is for PHP to check if a certain image file with a specific name exists in a specific directory, then echo the name of the file, but if it doesn't exist, then just show XXX.png.

I currently have a page (http://powerplantv2.jehzlau.net/ppm-deals) that echoes all product names from a certain attribute in Magento.

This page calls all images based on the attribute name. For example in my page there's an attribute name called "`cool haan`". So it automatically calls the image named "`coolhaan.png`". If there's an attribute name called "levis" then it will show an image named levis.png.

But I don't know how to add a condition if levis.png doesn't exist in the directory, I just want to call XXX.png.

How can I let PHP check first if the image exists that matches the certain attribute in the directory, then show attributename.png, if now, XXX.png.

Currently, below is my code:

```
<?php  
$name ='deals'; 
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem(); $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId(); 
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId); $ppmtenants = 
$attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); ?>
    <?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant): ?> 
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>media/wysiwyg/Deals/<?php echo strtolower($ppmtenantclean); ?>.png">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The code above gets all the options from a certain attribute then displays all the images with the attribute name. What I want to do is to check for the image name first before showing it.

To simplify my question, I just want to add a placeholder image with the name XXX.png for attributes with no images yet. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the answers posted so far are correct, but to make things easier for you, you can do something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant):
     if(file_exists($this->getUrl()."media/wysiwyg/Deals/".strtolower($ppmtenantclean).".png")) 
     { ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>media/wysiwyg/Deals/<?php echo strtolower($ppmtenantclean); ?>.png">
     <?php
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<img src="xxx.png" alt="No image" />';
      }
      ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Oh damn this is what I'm looking for. :D Thanks asprin! :D

Comment: And my apologies for not being able to figure out how to add the exact path to image. Now I know. :)

Comment: I just applied the code. It works pretty well Check it out: http://powerplantv2.jehzlau.net/ppm-deals. Thanks for saving me a loooooooot of time figuring it out myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use file_exists() http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php to check if the file exists and then display the image, otherwise output the placeholder image.

```
<?php if(file_exists(path_to_your_file)) {
// Image does exist, fetch the image
} else {
 // Image doesn't exist, output xxx.png
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks also for this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
if (!file_exists("PATH_TO_IMAGE") {
  //display xxx.png
} else {
  //load the image
}
```

Comment: the path to image changes depending on the attribute option in magento. How can I add it in the path to image? Should I use `if(!file_exists("$imagestringname.png") ` ?

Comment: format the image name as: `($imageStringName .".png")`
See how I needed to concatenate the two strings.